# Eclipse can't open JSP editor

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin, editor

Eclipse Platform - Version: 3.8.1, under Ubuntu 16.04

I have a webapp group of files I opened with a general Eclipse project. In here I got java and jsp files to work with.

I read that I could want to use another editor to better visualize and work with my code, so I downloaded the Marketplace and suggested plugins (Eclipse Web Developer Tools, Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment, Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools, Eclipse Java Development Tools) so I could switch to JAVA EE perspective and start the JSP Editor.

Done so, when I try to open any .jsp file I get the usual error others occurs in I paster below.

I suspect that Eclipse uses an uncorrect Java version, but can't find a way to check which it is. I read it should be in the file eclipse.ini in /usr/lib/eclipse but that file doesn't have references to anything similar (it should have a line with a `-vm`, which I have none).

I don't have ideas and hope some of you can enlight me!

Here is the Eclipse error:

```
Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/sse/core/internal/IExecutionDelegate
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createPart(EditorManager.java:875)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:609)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2949)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2854)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2846)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2797)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2777)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu$2.handleEvent(OpenWithMenu.java:180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core (383).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createPart(EditorManager.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2946)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.SSECorePlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.utils.StringUtils.unpack(StringUtils.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.projectHasNotBeenFullyScanned(TaskScanningJob.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.addProject(TaskScanningJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningScheduler.enqueue(TaskScanningScheduler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningScheduler.startup(TaskScanningScheduler.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.SSECorePlugin.start(SSECorePlugin.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.util.StringTokenizer
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 92 more
```

Comment: Eclipse 3.8.1 is pretty old, are you sure you installed versions of the web tools that are compatible with such an old release?

Comment: I just installed with apt-get install. Do you suggest to uninstall and reinstall a newer version, like 4.3? I'm new to IDEs so I don't really know if 3.8.1 is combatible or not..

Comment: Eclipse 4.6.2 (Neon.2) is the current release of Eclipse. Get it direct from eclipse.org

Comment: Wonder why Ubuntu repos make me download that old version then.. Hope with the new the problem won't occur.
Should I delete this question?

Comment: Ubuntu always seems to have very old versions of Eclipse for some reason.  It is up to you what you do with the question but it might just help someone else if you leave it.

Comment: Did you mean "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools" instead of "Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools"? I own several of the ones mentioned, and I don't see a "Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to download the latest Eclipse version from official site and all worked out. Don't use apt packets since they point to an older and probably unsupported Eclipse with fewer features.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the Ubuntu build is just broken if the `com.ibm.icu.util.StringTokenizer` class isn't loading; it's provided by the `com.ibm.icu` bundle, which is provided in the plain Eclipse Platform download.